# Editing the raw HTML inside a TinyMCE control

Tags: python, django, tinymce, django-tinymce

I have a Django website in which I use `django-tinymce` to edit HTML fields with a TinyMCE control.

TinyMCE practically gives me a WYSIWYG way to edit HTML. My question is, can I get access to edit the underlying HTML directly? I was thinking, maybe there's some button I can enbale which will toggle between "WYSIWYG mode" and "raw html mode" in TinyMCE. Is there one? If not, is there any elegant way to edit the HTML?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Simply add the `code` button to one of the toolbars, e.g. with this configuration for django-tinymce:

```
TINYMCE_DEFAULT_CONFIG = {
    # your other configuration
    'theme_advanced_buttons3_add': 'code',
}
```

[Here](http://wiki.moxiecode.com/index.php/TinyMCE:Control_reference#Default_buttons_available_in_the_advanced_theme)'s a list of buttons that are available with the `advanced` TinyMCE theme

Answer (score 4):

*django-tinymce* version 3 uses *TinyMCE* version 5 that requires enabling the [code button plugin](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/general-configuration-guide/customize-ui/#addingthecodebuttonplugin) and adding the `code` button to `toolbar`:

```py
TINYMCE_DEFAULT_CONFIG = {
    ...
    'plugins': 'code', # along with other plugins, e.g. 'link lists code'
    'toolbar': 'code', # along with other buttons, e.g. 'bold italic | code'
    ...
}
```

Comment: Nothing like waking up in the morning to see an answer to a question you asked over a decade ago :)

Comment: The question is still relevant and the answer may help others :). I spent half an hour digging this up, thought it might save that effort for the next guy/gal!